# Java constructor safety

Tags: java, constructor, try-catch

I've heard that when instantiating a Java object there are actually 2 code commands happening, the memory allocation and the actual constructor.

So when declaring a singleton we need to write it like this:

```
if (instance == null) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (instance == null) {
            var tmp = new SingletonObject();
            instance = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to know if this applies to `try` `catch` `finally` as well. or is this problem occur only in threads?

```
FileOutputSteam out = null;
try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(path);
    ...
} finally {
    if (out != null) { // Does out can be non null but be corrupt?
        out.close();
    }
}
// BTW: This is an example, I know that there is try-with-resource
```

Thanks,
Ido Sorozon

Comment: When it reaches `finally` block it must be a fully constructed `out` object

Comment: Your first example has nothing to do with any kind of _constructor safety_. It is just an example of the [Double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) for singletons.

Comment: @maba I am simply asking if this error is only a thread sync error or general error

Comment: @user7 Can I entrust that the javac/JVM will handle it for me(see maba's link)

Comment: Java guarantees that a non-null object reference has successfully executed its constructor without error. You can not have a "non null but corrupted" object, as long as the class does not require some extra steps to be initialized (thinking of InitializingBean of Spring or similar concepts)

Comment: @spi but in the first example it could occur, why is the second one different

Comment: @IdoSorozon no it can't. second example is "double-check locking" idiom, but only 1 call to instantiation. It's (a broken) attempt to prevent multithreading issues and save the cost of synchronisation whenever the object is already created (lazy initialisation without extra-synchronisation cost).

Comment: @spi see maba's link

Comment: @IdoSorozon yes I did. This has nothing to do with risky constructor. It only apply to multithreaded environment.

Comment: Have a look at https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#_safe_publication

Answer (score 1):

The null check in the `finally` block is there to avoid a `NullPointerException` because `out` may have failed initialization.

In other words, if the call to `new FileOutputStream(path)` ends in an exception, then `out` will not be set to an object. That means that the assignment `out = new FileOutputStream(path)` won't happen, and `out` will be `null`. And if it's null, `out.close()` in the `finally` block will encounter a `NullPointerException`.

Remember that `finally` will be run whether `new FileOutputStream(path)` raised an exception or not (that means, whether the assignment `out = new FileOutputStream(path)` failed or not), so the null check is there for the case where it failed.

And regarding `// Does out can be non null but be corrupt?`, then answer is `No`. In this `finally` block, `out` is either `null` (error occurred and assignment didn't happen) or a healthy `FileOutputStream` object resulting from a successful constructor call. **There's no partial state**.

Comment: How does this answares my question? Try to explain my question to yourself and you will see that your answare is not relevant

Comment: I guess the OP is concerned with *safe publication* in the first case (`var tmp = new SingletonObject(); instance = tmp;`)

Comment: @user7 I took it that the question assumes `out` won't be assigned at all if `new FileOutputStream(path)` raises an exception...

Comment: @ernest_k This is exactly what I asked, whether `out` will be assigned even when `new FileOutputStream(path)` throws an `Exception`

Comment: @IdoSorozon Yeah. I subsequently edited the post. See the very last part of the answer.

Comment: @ernest_k it wont be initialized even in a `catch` clause? And what is the difference between The first example and the second, does Java handle non local variables a different way than local variables? I've tried to recreate this error using Threads and I've failed miserably.

Comment: @IdoSorozon No, not even a catch block will encounter partial state. If `out` is set to anything other than `null` (anywhere after the constructor-calling statement), then the constructor ran successfully. The only way to have partial state is to modify a constructed object's fields (but that can only happen after constructor comples successfully).

Comment: @IdoSorozon The inconsistency that threads can raise is by checking `==null` and creating the object outside of a synchronized block. But the code you showed protects against this. And the chance of partial state here depends on how the the state is built (using a instance field directly is sure to cause this partial state if no synchronization is done... but there will only be a difference if multiple statements are used to construct the state, such as calling the constructor, then setters one by one. If not, the worst is that a thread will set something an have it overwritten by another)

Comment: @ernest_k if I would have written `instance = new ...` an error of patially constructed object could occur

Comment: @IdoSorozon If you're building the state with subsequent method statements, such as `instance.setX(x); instance.setY(y);...`, then yes. And if one of the `setX(x)...` fails with an exception after `instance = new...` has run, then again, yes, you would end up with partial state. But with these `setX(...` calls, you can have inconsistent state even without a failure, if there is no synchronization. **But** if these `setX..., setY...` operations are done in the constructor itself, then there's no way you can have partial state in a constructed object.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation of why that is necessary is wrong, but yes, if your singleton can be accessed by more than one thread, you need some locking mechanism in order to prevent two threads to initialize the singleton at the same time. You are using the double-checked locking pattern, which is one of the recommended ways to do that.

In your second example you are using local variables. They can only be accessed by the current thread, so no, you don't need to use synchronization there.

By the way, if you use Java 7 or higher, the try-with-resources construct is preferable:

```
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path)) {
    ...
}
```

which (except for the scope of `out`) is equivalent to your second snippet.

Comment: I see that you didn't read my question to the end, I've wtitten that I am aware that try-with-resource exist

Comment: @IdoSorozon Yes, I see now that I skipped reading the code comment at the end.